# Submit button transparent but not text

Tags: css, submit, transparent

I have a submit button. I want the background to be transparent (%),
but not the text. The text must remain with no transparency.
I have tried with following css:

```
opacity:0.2;
filter:alpha(opacity=40);
```

But that makes the whole submit button transperant including the text.
How do i make the text stay clean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rgba() values aren't supported in IE8, so for IE8 you can use this method:

Create a png which is larger than 1x1 pixel which matches the transparency of your background.

For IE9+ you can use `rgba(255,255,255,0.2);` on `background:` elements, this wont affect text at all.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
    
 #button{
    width: 52px;
    opacity:0.6;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
     }
    div
     {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    left:10;
    }
```

```
    <input type="submit" id="button" value=" ">
<div class="transbox">Submit</div>
```

I hope this code will help u